# Is there a way to consume a HashMap and get a vector of values in Rust?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have a `hashmap: HashMap<SomeKey, SomeValue>` and I want to consume the `hashmap` and get all its values as a vector.

The way I do it right now is

```
let v: Vec<SomeValue> = hashmap.values().cloned().collect();
```

`cloned` copies each value, but this construction doesn't consume the hashmap. I am OK with consuming the map.

Is there some way to get values without copying them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Convert the entire `HashMap` into an iterator and discard the keys:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn only_values<K, V>(map: HashMap<K, V>) -> impl Iterator<Item = V> {
    map.into_iter().map(|(_k, v)| v)
}
```

You can then do whatever you want with the iterator, including collecting it into a `Vec<_>`.

See also:

- [How do I collect the values of a HashMap into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56724014/155423)

Comment: The example on the doc site is almost exactly this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#examples-29

Answer (score 3):

Since Rust 1.54, you can use [`HashMap::into_values`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.into_values):

```rust
let v: Vec<_> = hashmap.into_values().collect();
```